# Robust hyper-parameter optimization for gaussian process

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit a gaussian process to some data using scikit-learn, but the maximum-likelihood estimation of the hyperparameters for the correlation model is failing with the following:

```
Exception: Bad parameter region. Try increasing upper bound
```

Now I suspect this is because of some massive 'spikes' (I hesitate to call them outliers because they may be true values) in my dataset - see the following plot (histogram on right):

[image]

So in my head the solution is to force the maximum likelihood optimiser to optimise only over the 1-99th percentile data, in order to ignore this spike. However I have no justification (or code yet) for this, and kind of wonder if anyone has any input on if this makes sense at all.

Maybe more generically: Would it make sense to have a 'robust' maximum-likelihood estimation of the hyperparameter?

Comment: did you try increasing the parameter regions? (`thetaU`, `thetaL`, and `theta0`?)

Comment: yes, as per their suggestions :-)